# Performance metrics on SQL Server Profiler and sp_trace commands

Tags: sql-server-2008

Are there any metrics available that indicate the varying performance of using MS SQL Profiler against the sp_trace commands on SQL Server 2008.  Most articles and writers seem to suggest that using sp_trace commands would be more efficient but is their any empirical evidence for this under varying workloads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe the reason you hear this suggestion is because SQL Server Profiler is merely the GUI front end that runs on top of [SQL Trace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191006.aspx)

From Brad McGeHee's [Mastering SQL Server Profiler](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/books/65797):

> What may be a surprise to many DBAs and developers is that SQL Server
>   Profiler is only a GUI designed to work with another feature of SQL
>   Server called SQL Trace. It is SQL Trace that is actually doing most
>   of the work when it comes to capturing SQL Server events and storing
>   them for later use. SQL Trace is a feature of SQL Server that can be
>   accessed indirectly with the Profiler GUI, system stored procedures,
>   or programmatically using Server Management Objects (SMO).
>
> In essence, SQL Trace is a very simple tool. Its job is just to
>   capture SQL Server-related communication between a client and SQL
>   Server. It acts similarly to a specialized network sniffer that
>   captures traffic on the network related to SQL Server and allows you
>   to see exactly which events are being sent from the client to SQL
>   Server.